# libnppig.so.8.0 Missing FFmpeg

Tags: linux, debian, video, ffmpeg, cuda

I've bought GeForce GTX 1050TI for testing FFmpeg with Nvidia encoder. 
Installed the requirements using CUDA Utils run file with these parameters: 
(I'm using Debian; I can't change to supported distro for a while.)

```
export PERL5LIB=.
./cuda-toolkit.run -override
```

The installation was successful.

I've built FFmpeg with this configuration:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp \
    --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

`make && make install` also successful.

I tried to run `ffmpeg` and the output of that:

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libnppig.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libnppig.so.8.0` exists in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

I tried this to include CUDA libraries, based on [this Linux Server Guide](https://linuxserverguide.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libavdevice-so-52-cannot-open-shared-object-file/),
but it's still not working.

Is there any solution for that, without changing distro?

Comment: @Antz: Thanks for catching (and correcting) spelling errors, but (1) please stop putting random formatting all over the place, and (2) please try to find and fix *all* the problems in any post you edit.

Comment: @ SudoSu:  If that ```./configure``` command is all one command (as I assume it must be), please append a backslash to the end of the first line (i.e., all lines except the last) and, ideally, indent the second line (i.e., all lines except the first) a few spaces.

Comment: It's a signle line just copied it wrong. I'm sorry for mistakes, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: It's no big deal — but this is an issue of presenting code clearly, and doesn't really have anything to do with English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself:

> EXPORT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

I really appreciate your misspelling fixes, but I needed help, not an English course.